# Automagically create a vector of defined objects?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Assume I have a macro that makes a class member in c++. Is there a way to modify the below example to automatically create `NumbersILike::nums`? Assume the objects created aren't the same `sizeof`.

```
#define MAKE_NUM(num) int num
class NumbersILike
{
    MAKE_NUM(three);
    MAKE_NUM(four);
    MAKE_NUM(five);
    std::vector<int*> nums = { &three,&four,&five };
};
```

Comment: I'm down with TMP solutions as well

Comment: You want reflection or metaclasses, coming in C++2x (or maybe 3x...)

Comment: I'd go with the code generating option (a script or external tool that generates C++ code) - in my experience it's easier to do than (ab)using the preprocessor for such tasks

Comment: "Good news guys, the C++ community has realized this is a problem, and you can expect a solution in 10 years."

Comment: @Carbon You down with TMP? (Yeah you know me!)

Comment: @Carbon You're welcome to join the Committee and magically find a way to make hundreds of people across the world with different needs and preferences agree on something to a timescale that suits you personally...

Comment: I see those questions quite often. The easy solution is to use an [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), the proper solution is to use boost preprocessor or a homemade alternative.

Comment: Why is the "answer" that says "I don't think it's possible," marked as the THE answer?

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: It gave me the vital hint to do it.

Comment: So edit the answer to make it an answer.

Comment: An edit is pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. I looked up 'X Macro'.

```
class NumbersILike
{
public:
#define LIST_OF_ITEMS \
X(three) \
X(four) \
X(five)

#define X(nm) int nm;
    LIST_OF_ITEMS
#undef X

    std::vector<int*> derp = {
    #define X(nm) &nm,
            LIST_OF_ITEMS
    #undef X
    };
};
```